# EC2 Server Seems to have port issues

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, asterisk, voip, elastix

I have installed an Elastix server on a m4.large instance,but I cannot get sound on any of my calls.

The server is configured as follows:
CentOS 5.9 
Elastix 2.4

Using the following guide:
https://thewebfellas.com/blog/how-to-install-elastix-onto-an-amazon-ec2-instance

I am able to register SIP phones, and SIP trunks.  But calls are not receiving an OK signal or any audio.  I tried both with specific rules for SIP and RTP ports, but the problem persists even when I open all ports.

Any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lack of audio in SIP calls is nearly *always* due to firewall or NAT issues. All traffic to/from your EC2 instance traverses a NAT, so I'd look into making sure that the requisite NAT setting in Elastix are set properly.

Comment: You were correct.  Thank you, the NAT settings in the manager were not actually being implemented.  I will post how I got them to work below.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason Elastix was ignoreing the NAT settings configured in the web interface.  I resolved this by adding the following lines to /etc/asterisk/sip_nat.conf

```
nat=yes
externip=<your_vdc_public_ip>
localnet=192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

Thank you to EEAA and this article that got me figured out:

http://community.voicepulse.com/articles/en_US/Article/Elastix-Template-NAT-Settings-to-Resolve-Disconnects